# Where are makepkg outputs packages built?

Tags: archlinux

I'm trying to install a AUR package. 
It seems easy, and I follow the Wiki description for it.
I downloaded the tarball, did `makepkg -S` to download the source and build it.

Apparently no error messages at output.
The process created some `tar.gz` files, that I tried to target when I use `pacman -U`
But none of them is the file expected by this command,

> 'missing metadata package in' ....

I did a research on web. I found that the place that `makepkg` output the package for Pacman is set in `makepkg.conf`, using `PKGDEST` item.

I changed that in `/etc/makepkg.conf`. It didn't create any file in that place when I tried to make that `AUR` package again (`makepkg -S -f`).

How to find the package for Pacman? Did the build go wrong and have no obvious message?

--Well .. after hours of search.. i give up and installed yaourt.. using that this to insall my package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg and my firsthand experience, they are put into the working directory by default:

> Next, one can configure where source files and packages should be placed and identify themselves as the packager. This step is optional; *packages will be created in the working directory where makepkg is run by default*.